# How to show the user the error when submitting a Django form?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-errors

I have created a Django form that creates a user through a custom user model, but if the form is invalid, the form disappears and leaves the button on the screen. I am trying to display the errors through `field.errors`.

```
<form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for field in registration_form %}
            <h5>{{ field.label_tag }}
                {{ field }}
                {% if field.help_text %}
                    <span>{{ field.help_text }}</span>
                {% endif %}
                
                {% for error in field.errors %}
                    <p>{{ error }}</p>
                {% endfor %}
                
            </h5>
        {% endfor %}
        <button type="submit">Join</button>
      </form>
```

Does anyone know what is wrong with the error part? (The form works; it just does not show any errors if it is not vallid.)

Comment: There are errors that are related to one field, and there are non_field_errors, that are related to the form as a whole, you seem to ignore the latter, that could be the reason why it doesn't show any errors maybe. I don't know, about the form completely disappearing though.

Comment: Share the related view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it like this:

```html
{% if form.errors %}
    {{ form.errors }}
{% endif %}
```